# URLSessionDownloadDelegate method didWriteData not called after app was in background

Tags: swift, background, nsurlsession

In my app I want to download big files. As such, I want to display download progress to the user. For this I implemented the `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`.

This works great until the app goes to the background. When the user then reopens the app `didWriteData` is not called. However `didFinishDownloadingTo` is still called. Hence it is not a problem with the delegate itself.

Some other developers reported similar issues in https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/229215#229215.

However, so far there seem to be no solutions or workarounds to this issue. Did anyone here find any workaround?
If no, what could I use instead of `SessionDownloadTask`?

Comment: File a bug at bugreport.apple.com.  I believe this is/was a known issue in some major iOS version recently.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in iOS12. As a workaround I resume all the download tasks once the application became active again. Like this:

```
private(set) var session: URLSession?

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    session?.getAllTasks(completionHandler: { tasks in
        for task in tasks {
            task.resume()
        }
    })
}
```